# how to find "File name and line number of Exception" in runtime

Tags: delphi-7

is there any component in Delphi7 to show more information about an exception in runtime like:

1. exception message and class
2. ".pas" file name
3. line number of exception

This information is very important when running the application on customer site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi 7 compiler does not include the filename or line number in the DCU. (Later versions make the filename available through RTTI, but it's not present in D7.)

You could use an exception handling package such as [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net) (free for non-commercial use,  and reasonably priced for a commercial version), [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/) (commercial, but I have no info on cost), or the [JEDI](http://www.delphi-jedi.org) JclDebug unit (Open Source), which can use the debugging information and information from a linker map file to provide a stack trace from the exception back. That stack trace includes the unit and line number (as well as the method or procedure name) where the exception occurred.

Comment: There's also [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/). I've used both EurekaLod and madExcept. Both works very well, but madExcept has prettier windows.

Comment: @GabrielF: I always forget Eureka; I've never used it. I've added it to the answer so it's more easily seen (with proper credit given to you, of course). Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: I didn't say "Only one of these"; I said "such as" and listed three examples. The answer to the question itself is in the first paragraph; the second paragraph is a suggested way to do something that isn't supported in Delphi 7, not a definitive list of the only ways to do it.

Comment: @Arioch'The: OK. I removed that single sentence. Happy now?

Comment: It became more consistent. I'm glad. But of course telling the generic name to google for would be better than just a list of products without their common denominator.

Comment: Dear, I Bought Mad Component but it is Only Work when I run My App inside of Delphi IDE and When I Deploy My Application , it doesn't Work.could you Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If you deploy a separate Release version of your project, you have to enable MadExcept in the Release configuration as well. By default, it's only enabled in the Debug release. To get line numbers and file names, you need the debug information available. MadExcept works perfectly well in deployed applications.

Comment: could you Please Help Complete step by step?after your Answer I Found Menu Item,But Can't Find Relative Option.

Comment: Project->Mad Except settings->Check the box that says "enable madExcept" at the top. Or, you know, you could [read the documentation](http://help.madshi.net/HowToUseMadExcept.htm).